# How do I find out what mail-server my host has installed for me?

Tags: email, mediatemple

I'm using MediaTemple's (dv) hosting service. How do I determine what mail-server is installed? Should I use the shell? If so, what command would be used?

Answer (score 14):

Go to the shell and type this command:

```
telnet <hostname> 25
```

This will come back with a line like so:

```
220 example.com ESMTP Exim 4.69 Thu, 13 Nov 2008 10:06:01 +1100
```

as you can see, this sever is running EXIM.

Then type QUIT to exit back to the shell.

---

**UPDATE:** Some hosts use a different address for their email server, if you are on Linux, you can type the following command to get a list of mail servers for a given domain:

```
dig -t MX example.com
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$ nmap -p 25 -A -T polite <hostname>
```

from a Linux box with nmap installed.